# Finding probability of at least one RV taking a specific value

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, random-field

Given a set of random variables $X = \{X_1, X_2, .. X_N\}$ where the domain of $X_i$ is $ \{ l_1, l_2, .. l_K \}, \forall i \in \{1,2 ... N\}$. I want to compute $P($ for at least one i, $ X_i = l_k)$. What is the best way to compute it?

Comment: You need more information: what is the multivariate distribution of $X$ and in what form is it given to you mathematically?  In many cases--especially when the $X_i$ are independent--the simplest approach is to compute the chance that none of the $X_i=l_k$ and subtract that chance from $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming independence, the probability that no $X_i=l_k$ is $\prod_i (1-P(X_i=l_k))$. So the probability that at least one $X_i=l_k$ is $1-\prod_i (1-P(X_i=l_k))$.